# Using global functions in AngelScript

Tags: c++, angelscript

I have a problem to make use of AngelScripts global functions inside a C++-application.

In my .cpp file I have the function:

```
int multi(int x, int y)
{
    int z = x * y;
    cout << x << endl;
    cout << y << endl;
    return z;
}
```

I'm registering it by using:

```
engine->RegisterGlobalFunction("int multi(int &out, int &out)", asFUNCTION(multi), asCALL_CDECL);
```

In my .as file I call the function like this:

```
multi(1, 2);
```

So in this case I want x to be 1 and y to be 2, but when I print the values with cout it's something like x = 4318096 and y = 4318100.

I can't figure out where my mistake is. I appreciate any help I can get.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You register this function wrong. It should be:

```
engine->RegisterGlobalFunction("int multi(int, int)", asFUNCTION(multi), asCALL_CDECL);
```

Out means this function will use this parameter as output.

Comment: thank you very much, I was sure it would be something that simple

Answer (score 0):

It should be:

```
engine->RegisterGlobalFunction("int multi(int, int)", asFUNCTION(multi), asCALL_CDECL);
```

When you use out it expects you to set the out value. And it doesn't get set before it enters the function. I'd you do it as I mentioned it will be set and doesn't expect it to be set. Good luck.